# reading text file in program and seperating them with arrays

Tags: arrays, text

'read text file like abc \n 1\n\2\n3 and read first array as string second array as number
'display first array that is string in text box and next array in text box

```
string fileContent;
string fileData;
fileContent = reader.ReadLine().Trim();
fileData = reader.ReadToEnd().Trim();
txt_employeeName.Text = fileContent.ToString();
string[] numbers;
char[] delimiters = { ' '};
numbers = fileData.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
//numbers = fileData.Split();
int value;
foreach (string num in numbers)
{
    num.Split('\n');
    //MessageBox.Show(num.ToString());
    txt_Monday.Text = num[0].ToString();
    txt_tuesday.Text = num[1].ToString();
    txt_wednesday.Text = num[2].ToString();
    txt_thursday.Text = num[3].ToString();
    txt_friday.Text = num[4].ToString();
    txt_saturday.Text = num[5].ToString();
    txt_sunday.Text = num[6].ToString();

    for (int i= 0 ; i < num.Length; i++)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(num[i].ToString());
    } */
    // convert the token to an int - if fails, give up
```

Comment: Is this java or javascript? If it is or not, you should include the respective tag of the language you're using...

Comment: read this guide https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for improving your question